# Is there any API service to retrieve abstract of a journal article?

Tags: publications, journals, doi

There are some API services to give title, citation and authors of an article by its DOI. I wonder if there is a service to provide abstract of a journal article by providing its DOI.

Answer (score 4):

For the MEDLINE database, with the E-utilities you can:

1. Use the [`esearch`](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#_chapter4_EFetch_) function to retrieve the PubMed ID (PMID) of the article that includes the DOI as a `term` (presumably only one article):

   [`http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&WebEnv=1&usehistory=y&term=10.1021/bi902153g`](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&WebEnv=1&usehistory=y&term=10.1021/bi902153g)
2. Then, use [`efetch`](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#_chapter4_EFetch_) function to retrieve the abstract among other bibliographic attributes of the article (you need to pass the `query_key` and `WebEnv` returned earlier by `esearch`).

   `http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=XML&rettype=abstract&query_key=1&WebEnv=something`

---

If you have the `PMID`, it is one step with `efetch`:

- [`http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=17284678&retmode=XML&rettype=abstract`](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=17284678&retmode=XML&rettype=abstract)

Comment: The edit is based on [this Biostars answer](https://www.biostars.org/p/1625/#1628)

Comment: This is only for the pubmed papers but any idea what we can do with other journals that are not in pubmed.

Comment: @ypriverol: That's going to depend entirely on the journal. Give a field, and people can give better answers.

Comment: @tonysdy I'm looking for something like crossref?